# How to hide blocks based on menu_name

Tags: 7, nodes, routes

I've a site with a main menu, and submenus as block. If I'm on node "50" I want to hide every submenu, except the submenu with the link to node "50".

**Question**: How can I hide a block based on it's variable menu_name (I think it is this variable) without javascript.

Here's a [wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eayID.png), so you can get an overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) for this purpose.  You can specify which levels of which menu you want to show, and the blocks display conditionally depending on the current active trail.

Comment: It was exactly the module I was looking for. Thank you Danielle for saving time :)